# SPARK 2.1.1: Active batches are queued up when used sliding window

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, spark-streaming

I am developing a streaming application in Apache Spark 2.1.1 with Sliding window of Duration X sec. and slide Y sec.(I have tried different values for X and Y). I am reading the messages from kafka (27 partitions) using `.createDirectStream`. My cluster configuration is,

- Total executor cores=135
- Nodes=3
- Core per executors= 5
- Executor memory = 10G

When I tried to execute the job with Window duration of X=5 sec. and slide Y= 1 sec. There are no active batches queued up. According to my logic this is because (# of total cores =135) and (# of task created= # kafka partitions * windowed batches= 27*5=135) in this case.

Now in other case when window duration X=120 sec. and slide y=1 sec., (# of task created= 27*120= 3240) which is far more than available cores (135). Hence the 
huge queue is observed and lots of time is required in Scheduling.

Is my interpretation correct? if yes, then what will be the remedy for it?

Answer (score 1):

Although hard to be 100% sure without looking into the cluster, your interpretation seems to be correct. The task dispatching overhead can take its toll in low-latency applications.

One possible approach to solving this is to use a window-based reduction instead, like `reduceByKeyAndWindow` and in particular, the overload that takes an invertible function if your use-case allows for it: `reduceByKeyAndWindow(func, invFunc, windowLength, slideInterval, [numTasks])`

Also note that it's possible to force a reduction of the number of partitions using this call: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/PairDStreamFunctions.scala#L303

Comment: Thanx Maasg. For my use case I am using sliding window of 120s duration and 1s slide, which is followed by a SQL query to find max and min and included groupBy clause. Can u please suggest, that how can I implement the SQL functionality with `reduceByKeyAndWindow` function?